# Howto get text of equal aligned columns 1 and 3 top aligned when col 2 has a starting paragraph

Tags: html, css

In the following example of equal height columns the presence of the paragraph starting text in the 2nd column is pushing the top of the text in columns 1 and 3 down which i would like to get aligned at the very top of the column. Any ideas?

```css
.col-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<h2>Equal Height Columns</h2>
<p>Make the columns match the height of the tallest column.</p>
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col" style="background:orange">
    <div>Top Aligned</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="background:yellow">
    <p>Para pushes previous cell content down</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="background:orange">
    <div>Column top aligned </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you can add a scratch for demonstration?

Comment: Thanks for looking at the issue - sorry I didn't make the problem clear. http://plnkr.co/edit/QPuzIYBKK5AbkQBbIh7V?p=preview     Are you able to see the like sample on plnkr....if you remove the text from the middle column you will see the text on columns 1 and 3 moves to the top of the cell.....if i don't use a p tag in column 2 and use a div instead i dont have the problem..but our users are free to put P tags in.

Comment: use with in px; not %

Comment: give your content height and width in px and also put some margin to it . it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most general solution I can thnik of - whatever element is top of the content of the column, make sure it has no top margin.

> .col > *:first-child{
>    margin-top:0px;
>   }

Answer (score 0):

This problem goes away when you apply `p {margin: 0;}`. That is because the default styling of the browser adds margin to `p` tags automatically.

The default user agent stylesheet for `p` is:

```
p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

Thus, if you use `p {margin: 0;}`, the content won't be pushed by the paragraph.

```css
.col-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;

    }
    
p {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<h2>Equal Height Columns</h2>
<p>Make the columns match the height of the tallest column.</p>

<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col" style="background:orange">
    <div>Top Aligned - this text should be at the top of the cell</div>

  </div>

  <div class="col" style="background:yellow">


    <p>Para pushes previous cell content down - remove this and you see text of previous column and following column shifts up to the top</p>

  </div>

  <div class="col" style="background:orange">

    <div>Column top aligned </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my paragraphs need the margin so as the paragraph layout is not affected.I'm trying to figure out a way of left and right columns touching the top regardless of whatever elements are in the middle column - they could be h2, h3, a, ul, ol etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.col-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;

}
.col {
    display: table-cell;

    }

    p{
      margin-left:10px;

    }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<h2>Equal Height Columns</h2>
<p>Make the columns match the height of the tallest column.</p>

<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col" style="background:orange">
    <p>Top Aligned - this text should be at the top of the cell</p>

  </div>

  <div class="col" style="background:yellow">


    <p>Para pushes previous cell content down</p>


  </div>

  <div class="col" style="background:orange">

    <p>Column top aligned </p>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

try this.

Comment: thanks - No, that didn't work. That only put space (margin) on the left column - I'm looking to remove the space at the top of the column so it hits the top border of the column. I can't change the CSS on the P as the P element is only sample content it could be any element.